# Linux Terminal SSH Username Change

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, root, xterm

I want to connect via ssh to my Ubuntu server from my Linux PC.

Xterm uses my Linux PC username for the login. I've another username on the server. It's not the same name like on my Linux PC. How can I change the username? The client always says that the password is incorrect with the clients username.

Comment: `ssh username@ubuntuserver`...

Comment: Actually it is not Xterm that sets the user name. It is the behavior of SSH.

Comment: did you read the man page for ssh?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to username (form Ubuntuserver) with which you wish to connect to your Ubuntu machine like this:

```
ssh username@ubuntuserver
```

If you do not specify the username it will try to login to the server with your current username (from linuxpc)

Answer (score -1):

Use SSH like this

```
ssh remote_user@remote_host
```